# Symfony2: How to call PHP function from controller?

Tags: php, symfony

I need use a PHP function to convert numbers to letters. I create a file named: converter.php in the folder “Controller”. I need call the function named “convertir_numero_letras($number)” insert in converter.php.
I call the function “convertir_numero_letras($number)” from the following controller:

```
public function convertirAction()
    {
        $number=1234;
        $this->convertir_numero_letras($number);

        return  $this->render('contratos/mostrar_cifra.html.twig', array('numero_convertido' => $numero_convertido));

    }
```

But this code not work. I obtain the following
 error message:

Attempted to call an undefined method named "convertir_numero_letras" of class "BackendBundle\Controller\ContratosController".

As I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a folder inside bundle like yourBundel/Helper
and create you custom class in folder like ConverHelper.php
like this :

```
class ConvertHelper
{
    public static function numero_letras($param)
    {
        return 'converted value';
    }
}
```

and then you can call in any controller and any bundle like this:

```
yourBundle\helper\ConverterHelper::numero_letras('someting');
```

don't forget to add namespace of ConverterHelper to your contoller file

example:

```
// file: GRF/BlogBundle/Helper/ConverterHelper.php
<?php

namespace GRF\BlogBundle\Helper;


class ConverterHelper
{
    public static function toNum($param)
    {
        return $param;
    }
}
```

and usage in controller:

```
//file controller
    <?php

namespace GRF\BlogBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;


class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new Response(\GRF\BlogBundle\Helper\ConverterHelper::toNum(32434));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but the solution that you propose does not work. I get the following error message : **The autoloader expected class "BackendBundle\Controller\ContratosController" to be defined in file "C:\proyectos\cursospierobis/src\BackendBundle\Controller\ContratosController.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.  **

Comment: i test it in empty project ,it works fine,when converter folder added and create class ,put this code in my controller - pay attention to namespace-  exit(\someBundleName\Helper\ConverterHelper::toNum(32434)); -- and class converter should be in helper namespace

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. In a moment I'll try again apply the solution you propose.